# Is it possible to apply & maintain the CIS Benchmarks Compliance on Managed Kubernetes Clusters such as Azure Kubernetes Service?

Tags: kubernetes, benchmarking, azure-aks

I have a managed Kubernetes cluster over Azure Public Cloud. I tried to make some changes on the nodes to satisfy 1 Host Compliance provided by CIS Benchmark Guide for Kubernetes. Then I upgraded a node regarding size. And the host compliance failed again. It was reset on that node. How do I maintain all the changes on the nodes?

I did ssh over the nodes and did the change over there. But compliance failed after the node upgrade.

Comment: What changes exactly have you implemented to be compliant with CIS?

Comment: I changed a couple of flags related to Docker Daemon and some of the files permissions e.g. I changed the File Permissions of /etc/kubernetes/pki.

Comment: Majorly I need to change many file permissions which I think will be reset once the node is upgraded from Azure side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [Reconfigure a Node's Kubelet in a Live Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/), but it's for Cluster configuration.

As for the changes on the node itself, I recommend reading [Security hardening in AKS virtual machine hosts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/security-hardened-vm-host-image?view=azure-cli-latest).

> AKS clusters are deployed on host virtual machines, which run a security optimized OS. This host OS is currently based on an Ubuntu 16.04.LTS image with a set of additional security hardening steps applied (see Security hardening details).
>
> The goal of the security hardened host OS is to reduce the surface area of attack and allow the deployment of containers in a secure fashion.
>
> **Important**
>
> The security hardened OS is NOT CIS benchmarked. While there are overlaps with CIS benchmarks, the goal is not to be CIS-compliant. The goal for host OS hardening is to converge on a level of security consistent with Microsoft’s own internal host security standards.

If you need to make any changes then I would advice setting up your own cluster manually using `kubeadm`. Just get virtual servers configure them your way and use [Creating a single control-plane cluster with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) or any other guide that fits your needs.